# Get a SoftwareBitmap from HTTP GET in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, http-get

I'm working on a project where I need to process a file with OCR,

and since I'm not allowed to access files directly in UWP, I had only two choices : 
file picker (undesirable), or getting the files from an Http server,

I was able to use the file picker and this was my implementation:

```
SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;

FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

var inputFile = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await inputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
    softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
}

OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(new Windows.Globalization.Language("fr-FR"));
OcrResult ocrResults = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(softwareBitmap);
OcrLine ocrResult = ocrResults.Lines[0];

string text = ocrResult.Text;
```

Now I'm trying to get the file from an HTTP GET request instead, but I could not figure out how to have it in `SoftwareBitmap` format (which the `OcrEngine` accepts)

from this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7d8241cd-8d99-4f97-b466-0c1f094047af/uwpxaml-how-to-build-a-bitmapimage-file-from-a-web-request-stream?forum=wpdevelop), I found this useful code sample with which I get the file in `BitmapImage` format

```
private async void Populate()
{
    string QRServiceAPI = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data={0}&size={1}x{2}";
    string q = string.Format(QRServiceAPI, "http://solatys.com", 150, 150);
    using (var d = new Downloader())
    {
        var feed = await d.GetDataFeed(q);
        feed.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();

        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes((byte[])feed.ToArray());
                writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
            }
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(ms);
            Image1.Source = image;
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to either convert this `BitmapImage` to `SoftwareBitmap`? 
or how can I get it as `SoftwareBitmap` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the HttpClient to get your image and converting the content stream to an IRandomAccessStream

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://my.image");
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
```

From there it's the same as you already have

```
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
```

Note that `AsRandomAccessStream` is an extension method in the `System.IO` namespace.